# Mapping class name in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am building an application that have an object called `Element`. The class consists of 2 fields (in fact there are more but the other are irrelevant):

- `ElementData` - a set of data (key - value) with some additional features
- `ElementType` - interface with multiple implementations. Encapsulated set of business rules and validators - doesn't get any values

Simplified class diagram:

[image]

I have few classes implementing `ElementType` interfce:

```php
class Type1 implements ElementType {/*...*/}
class Type2 implements ElementType {/*...*/}
class Type3 implements ElementType {/*...*/}
```

My database table for elements is also very simple and has only 2 relevant fields (the rest removed from the screenshot):

[image]

Here the problem arises. I have no idea how to map a class (Type1, Type2...) and save it as a string (type1, type2...) in the `elements` table (like a normal embedded element). I searched the documentation and didn't find anything useful.
My current mapping file looks like this:

```
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                   https://raw.github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/master/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="App\Domain\Element" table="elements" repository-class="App\Repository\ElementRepository">
        <embedded name="id" class="App\Domain\ElementId" use-column-prefix="false" />
        <!--Missing mapping here-->
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. Maybe my solution will be helpful for someone. The solution bases on a [custom mapping type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html).

```php
<?php

namespace App\Mapping;

use App\Domain\ElementType;
use App\Domain\Type1;
use App\Domain\TypeFactory;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class ElementType extends Type
{
    const NAME = 'element_type';

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $column, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $platform->getVarcharTypeDeclarationSQL($column);
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return TypeFactory::getTypeByString($value);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if (!$value instanceof ElementType) {
            throw new \Exception('Wrong type');
        }

        return TypeFactory::getStringByType($value);
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return self::NAME;
    }
}
```

`TypeFactory` is just a simple switch statement so I won't paste it here.

```
# config/packages/doctrine.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            element_type:  App\Mapping\ElementType
```

When my custom mapping type was created, all I had to do was to implement it in my mapper:

```
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                   https://raw.github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/master/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="App\Domain\Element" table="elements" repository-class="App\Repository\ElementRepository">
        <embedded name="id" class="App\Domain\ElementId" use-column-prefix="false" />
        <field name="type" type="element_type" />
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```